# hr element does not display/makes view blank ionic

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

How to make a hr element appear at ionic framework? When i do hr, it shows nothing/invisible, or view get's blank.

There is a ionic compenent to make hrs (v1)? If there is, which one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use this to test if it would show up;

```
hr {
  border: 2px solid red !important;
  height: 10px !important;
  width: 500px !important;
  background: blue !important;
  display: block !important;
  font-size: 2em !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Note: This is just a test. using "!important" is not ideal. From here you should try and determine why it is not showing

Answer (score 10):

I don't have much experience with Ionic, but you could try to define a CSS class that renders exactly the same thing as `<hr />` element. I think that should work.

```css
.hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="hr"> </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6qs02538/

Comment: Unfortunatelly, hr is still missing. Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens when you increase the border width to 2 or 3 pixels?

Comment: It need the visibility setting to visible. It's set to hidden in Ionic by default.

Answer (score 8):

In Ionic 4 you also need to set a background-color for the hr, e.g.:

```
hr {background: black;}
```

Answer (score 2):

if anyone is still facing this problem , use ion-item-divider tag

Comment: That leaves a thick bar which isn't really appropriate as a hr replacement. Sadly, it does appear to be the only option.

Answer (score 0):

I am using bootstrap.min.css other than that I have no reason for <hr /> to not show up. However, I need the code below to see a thin line. Setting the visibility and background did nothing.

```
hr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 10px 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Notice how I am not using a class to set the properties. I just use `<hr/>` directly in the html. (In the answer above s/he uses a class name and applies it to an div. As such, `<div class="hr">`